# Jquery Javascript fadein when click and fadeout when finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  $('.showloader').click(function () {
      $('.loader').fadeIn();

  });
```

I have a loading css called .loader
It is default 
Display:none

I would like to have it display when click the .showloader . This will submit a register form that has jquery validated method.

What is the best way to fadeOut this div tag if the user enter the wrong input validate or forget to input some field and they have to enter the data again.

Thanks

Comment: I guess the `validate` has a callback action ... so there you can fadeout the element

Comment: I found the answer from this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505053/jquery-validation-plugin-add-remove-class-to-from-elements-error-container

Answer (score 0):

I Have found the answer from this post : [jQuery Validation plugin: add/remove class to/from element's error container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505053/jquery-validation-plugin-add-remove-class-to-from-elements-error-container)

Just use highlight method inside validate

```
$('#indexform').validate({
    rules: {
      firstName: {
        required: true
      },
      lastName: {
        required: true
      },
      address1: {
        required: true
      },
      city: {
        required: true
      },
      state: {
        required: true
      },
      country: {
        required: true
      },
      zip: {
        required: true,
        rangelength: [5,5],
        digits: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      zip: 'Zip code must be 5 digits'
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $('.loader').fadeOut();
    },
```